# Getting undefined instead of string

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

The output of this program is undefined instead of string name.
     I am taking a date as input to the program and comparing the date with the existing dates of president array. In case if the date matches then i want to return the president name for that particular date

```
process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');

var stdin = '';
process.stdin.on('data', function (chunk) {
  //printing the value returned by presidentOnDate function
  console.log(JSON.stringify(presidentOnDate(chunk)));
});


//This is presidents array
 var presidents = [

      {"number":32,"president":"Franklin D. Roosevelt","took_office":"1933-03-04","left_office":"1945-04-12"},

      {"number":33,"president":"Harry S. Truman","took_office":"1945-04-12","left_office":"1953-01-20"},

      {"number":34,"president":"Dwight D. Eisenhower","took_office":"1953-01-20","left_office":"1961-01-20"},

      {"number":35,"president":"John F. Kennedy","took_office":"1961-01-20","left_office":"1963-11-22"},

      {"number":36,"president":"Lyndon B. Johnson","took_office":"1963-11-22","left_office":"1969-01-20"},

      {"number":37,"president":"Richard Nixon","took_office":"1969-01-20","left_office":"1974-08-09"},

      {"number":38,"president":"Gerald Ford","took_office":"1974-08-09","left_office":"1977-01-20"},

      {"number":39,"president":"Jimmy Carter","took_office":"1977-01-20","left_office":"1981-01-20"},

      {"number":40,"president":"Ronald Reagan","took_office":"1981-01-20","left_office":"1989-01-20"},

      {"number":41,"president":"George H. W. Bush","took_office":"1989-01-20","left_office":"1993-01-20"},

      {"number":42,"president":"Bill Clinton","took_office":"1993-01-20","left_office":"2001-01-20"},

      {"number":43,"president":"George W. Bush","took_office":"2001-01-20","left_office":"2009-01-20"},

      {"number":44,"president":"Barack Obama","took_office":"2009-01-20","left_office":"2017-01-20"}

    ];
```

//PresidentOnDate function which should return a president name based on input date

```
function presidentOnDate(date) {
    var output="";
       for(var i=0;i<presidents.length;i++){
           //console.log(presidents[i].took_office);
           if((presidents[i].took_office)==date){
              output+=presidents[i].president;
           }
      }
   return output;
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to `stringify` the result of `presidentOnDate`? It doesn't return an object

Comment: Please post an example that reproduces your issue. Where exactly in your code do you do what exactly?

Comment: check for date. Whether the format and value is same as of presidents[i].took_office.

Comment: results will be dependent on what you are passing as the date param to presidentOnDate

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you are passing in a buffer instead of a string.

Try changing the `chunk` buffer to a string before passing it to `presidentOnDate`.

So instead of `presidentOnDate(chunk)` try `presidentOnDate(chunk.toString())`

Answer (score 0):

Try this function it's working fine.

problem you facing when you take input it take \r\n also so when you compare both you get false that y output showing null.

EX:input string: "2009-01-20\r\n"  compare with : took_office: "2009-01-20" => result false

EX: input string with trim: "2009-01-20"   compare with : took_office: "2009-01-20"  => result True

**change only :  (presidents[i].took_office) ==date.trim()**

```
function presidentOnDate(date) {

var output="";
   for(var i=0;i<presidents.length;i++){
       if((presidents[i].took_office) ==date.trim()){

          output+= presidents[i].president;
       }
  }

    return output;
 }
```